# ¿Alguien sabe como desencriptar este código .js?

Tags: javascript, desofuscación

```
var _0x5f04 = ["\x44\x56\x43\x72", "\x79\x70\x74", "\x63\x61", "\x6C\x6C", "\x69\x6E\x64", "\x65\x78\x4F\x66", "\x6C\x65\x6E", "\x67\x74\x68", "\x61\x70", "\x70\x6C\x79", "\x66\x72\x6F", "\x6D\x43\x68", "\x61\x72\x43", "\x6F\x64\x65", "\x63\x68\x61", "\x72\x41\x74", "\x72\x43\x6F\x64", "\x65\x41\x74", "\x63\x61\x6C\x6C", "\x73\x74\x72\x69\x6E\x67", "\x37\x5A\x53", "\x63\x61\x6C\x6C\x65\x65", "\x73\x65\x74", "\x70\x75\x73\x68", "\x73\x68\x69\x66\x74", "\x54\x4A\x4B", "\x2B\x57\x3D", "\x63\x56\x74", "\x42\x43\x61\x73", "\x64\x65\x66\x69\x6E\x65\x50\x72\x6F\x70\x65\x72\x74\x79", "\x79\x66\x30", "\x67\x7A\x41\x38", "\x75\x76\x77", "\x44\x45\x71", "\x33\x58\x48", "\x6D\x61\x70", "\x2F\x31\x52\x4D", "\x4E\x4F\x49", "\x4C\x50\x51\x55", "\x34\x6B\x6C", "\x6D\x36", "\x35\x59\x62", "", "\x64\x65\x46", "\x72\x78\x32", "\x68\x69\x6A\x39", "\x6E\x6F\x70", "\x65\x78\x65\x63", "\x72\x65\x70\x6C\x61\x63\x65", "\x47"];
! function() {
    var _0xc87cx1 = [_0x5f04[0], _0x5f04[1], _0x5f04[2], _0x5f04[3], _0x5f04[4], _0x5f04[5], _0x5f04[6], _0x5f04[7], _0x5f04[8], _0x5f04[9], _0x5f04[10], _0x5f04[11], _0x5f04[12], _0x5f04[13], _0x5f04[14], _0x5f04[15], _0x5f04[16], _0x5f04[17], _0x5f04[18], _0x5f04[19], _0x5f04[20], _0x5f04[21], _0x5f04[22], _0x5f04[23], _0x5f04[24], _0x5f04[25], _0x5f04[26], _0x5f04[27], _0x5f04[28], _0x5f04[29], _0x5f04[30], _0x5f04[31], _0x5f04[32], _0x5f04[33], _0x5f04[34], _0x5f04[35], _0x5f04[36], _0x5f04[37], _0x5f04[38], _0x5f04[39], _0x5f04[40], _0x5f04[41], _0x5f04[42], _0x5f04[43], _0x5f04[44], _0x5f04[45], _0x5f04[46], _0x5f04[47], _0x5f04[48], _0x5f04[49]];
    (function(_0xc87cx2, _0xc87cx3, _0xc87cx4, _0xc87cx5, _0xc87cx6, _0xc87cx7, _0xc87cx8, _0xc87cx9) {
        function _0xc87cxa(_0xc87cx1) {
            return typeof _0xc87cx1 == _0xc87cx16 && _0xc87cx13()
        }

        function _0xc87cxb(_0xc87cx1) {
            return _0xc87cx4[_0xc87cx9[_0xc87cx1c]](_0xc87cx1)
        }

        function _0xc87cxc(_0xc87cx2) {
            return _0xc87cx8[_0xc87cx9[_0xc87cx1a]](null, {
                length: _0xc87cx2
            })[_0xc87cx1[35]](Number[_0xc87cx9[_0xc87cx19]], Number)
        }

        function _0xc87cxd(_0xc87cx1, _0xc87cx2, _0xc87cx3, _0xc87cx4) {
            return (_0xc87cx4 + _0xc87cx2 + _0xc87cx1[_0xc87cx9[_0xc87cx1f]](_0xc87cx3 % _0xc87cx1[_0xc87cx9[_0xc87cx21]])) % _0xc87cx22
        }

        function _0xc87cxe(_0xc87cx2, _0xc87cx3) {
            var _0xc87cx4, _0xc87cx5 = _0xc87cxc(_0xc87cx22),
                _0xc87cx6 = _0xc87cx19,
                _0xc87cx7 = _0xc87cx1[42];
            for (i = _0xc87cx19; i < _0xc87cx22; i++) {
                _0xc87cx6 = _0xc87cxd(_0xc87cx2, _0xc87cx5[i], i, _0xc87cx6), _0xc87cx4 = _0xc87cx5[i], _0xc87cx5[i] = _0xc87cx5[_0xc87cx6], _0xc87cx5[_0xc87cx6] = _0xc87cx4
            };
            i = _0xc87cx19, _0xc87cx6 = _0xc87cx19;
            for (var _0xc87cx8 = _0xc87cx19; _0xc87cx8 < _0xc87cx3[_0xc87cx9[_0xc87cx21]]; _0xc87cx8++) {
                i = (i + _0xc87cx27) % _0xc87cx22, _0xc87cx6 = (_0xc87cx6 + _0xc87cx5[i]) % _0xc87cx22, _0xc87cx4 = _0xc87cx5[i], _0xc87cx5[i] = _0xc87cx5[_0xc87cx6], _0xc87cx5[_0xc87cx6] = _0xc87cx4, _0xc87cx7 += _0xc87cxb(_0xc87cx3[_0xc87cx9[_0xc87cx1f]](_0xc87cx8) ^ _0xc87cx5[(_0xc87cx5[i] + _0xc87cx5[_0xc87cx6]) % _0xc87cx22])
            };
            return _0xc87cx7;
        }

        function _0xc87cxf(_0xc87cx1) {
            var _0xc87cx1 = _0xc87cx1[_0xc87cx9[_0xc87cx1f]](_0xc87cx19);
            return _0xc87cx1 >= _0xc87cx1e && _0xc87cx23 >= _0xc87cx1 && _0xc87cx13() ? _0xc87cx1 += _0xc87cx25 : _0xc87cx1 >= _0xc87cx24 && _0xc87cx26 >= _0xc87cx1 && _0xc87cx13() && (_0xc87cx1 -= _0xc87cx25), _0xc87cx17[_0xc87cx9[_0xc87cx27]](_0xc87cxb(_0xc87cx1));
        }

        function _0xc87cx10() {
            var _0xc87cx2, _0xc87cx3, _0xc87cx4, _0xc87cx11, _0xc87cx5, _0xc87cx7 = _0xc87cx1[42],
                _0xc87cx8 = arguments[_0xc87cx19],
                _0xc87cxa = _0xc87cx1[42],
                _0xc87cxc = _0xc87cx1[42],
                _0xc87cxd = _0xc87cx19;
            (_0xc87cx15[_0xc87cx1[47]](_0xc87cx8) || !_0xc87cx13()) && (_0xc87cx8 = _0xc87cx8[_0xc87cx1[48]](_0xc87cx15, _0xc87cx1[42]));
            do {
                _0xc87cx4 = _0xc87cxf(_0xc87cx8[_0xc87cx9[_0xc87cx29]](_0xc87cxd++)), _0xc87cx11 = _0xc87cxf(_0xc87cx8[_0xc87cx9[_0xc87cx29]](_0xc87cxd++)), _0xc87cx5 = _0xc87cxf(_0xc87cx8[_0xc87cx9[_0xc87cx29]](_0xc87cxd++)), _0xc87cxc = _0xc87cxf(_0xc87cx8[_0xc87cx9[_0xc87cx29]](_0xc87cxd++)), _0xc87cx2 = _0xc87cx4 << _0xc87cx21 | _0xc87cx11 >> _0xc87cx1c, _0xc87cx3 = (_0xc87cx11 & _0xc87cx20) << _0xc87cx1c | _0xc87cx5 >> _0xc87cx21, _0xc87cxa = (_0xc87cx5 & _0xc87cx1a) << _0xc87cx1f | _0xc87cxc, _0xc87cx7 += _0xc87cxb(_0xc87cx2), _0xc87cx5 != _0xc87cx28 && _0xc87cx13() && (_0xc87cx7 += _0xc87cxb(_0xc87cx3)), _0xc87cxc != _0xc87cx28 && _0xc87cx13() && (_0xc87cx7 += _0xc87cxb(_0xc87cxa)), _0xc87cx2 = _0xc87cx3 = _0xc87cxa = _0xc87cx1[42], _0xc87cx4 = _0xc87cx11 = _0xc87cx5 = _0xc87cxc = _0xc87cx1[42]
            } while (_0xc87cxd < _0xc87cx8[_0xc87cx9[_0xc87cx21]]);;
            return _0xc87cx6(_0xc87cx7);
        }

        function _0xc87cx12() {
            return _0xc87cx2a.toString()[_0xc87cx1[48]](/[^\S]/gm, _0xc87cx1[42])
        }

        function _0xc87cx13() {
            return _0xc87cx12()[_0xc87cx9[_0xc87cx21]] == _0xc87cx1b
        }

        function _0xc87cx14() {
            var _0xc87cx1 = arguments;
            _0xc87cx1[_0xc87cx27] = _0xc87cxe(_0xc87cx1[_0xc87cx19], _0xc87cx10(_0xc87cx1[_0xc87cx27])), _0xc87cx1[_0xc87cx21] = _0xc87cxe(_0xc87cx5, _0xc87cx10(_0xc87cx1[_0xc87cx21])), _0xc87cx1[_0xc87cx19] == _0xc87cx1[_0xc87cx21] && _0xc87cx13() && new _0xc87cx7(_0xc87cx1[_0xc87cx27])[_0xc87cx9[_0xc87cx19]](window);
        }
        var _0xc87cx15 = /[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g,
            _0xc87cx16 = _0xc87cx1[19],
            _0xc87cx17 = _0xc87cx1[20],
            _0xc87cx18 = arguments,
            _0xc87cx19 = 0,
            _0xc87cx1a = 3,
            _0xc87cx1b = 2662,
            _0xc87cx1c = 4,
            _0xc87cx1d = 8,
            _0xc87cx1e = 65,
            _0xc87cx1f = 6,
            _0xc87cx20 = 15,
            _0xc87cx21 = 2,
            _0xc87cx22 = 256,
            _0xc87cx23 = 90,
            _0xc87cx24 = 97,
            _0xc87cx25 = 32,
            _0xc87cx26 = 122,
            _0xc87cx27 = 1,
            _0xc87cx28 = 64,
            _0xc87cx29 = 5,
            _0xc87cx2a = _0xc87cx18[_0xc87cx1d][_0xc87cx1[21]],
            _0xc87cx2b = [],
            _0xc87cx18 = arguments,
            _0xc87cx2c = new _0xc87cx3;
        _0xc87cx2c[_0xc87cx1[22]] = function(_0xc87cx2) {
            _0xc87cx2 == _0xc87cx5 && _0xc87cx13() && !_0xc87cx2b[_0xc87cx9[_0xc87cx21]] ? _0xc87cx2b = [!0] : 1 == _0xc87cx2b[_0xc87cx19] && _0xc87cx13() && (_0xc87cx2b[_0xc87cx9[_0xc87cx21]] == _0xc87cx27 || _0xc87cxa(_0xc87cx2b[_0xc87cx27]) && (_0xc87cx2b[_0xc87cx9[_0xc87cx21]] == _0xc87cx21 || _0xc87cx2b[_0xc87cx9[_0xc87cx21]] == _0xc87cx1a && _0xc87cxa(_0xc87cx2b[_0xc87cx21]))) ? _0xc87cx2b[_0xc87cx1[23]](_0xc87cx2) : _0xc87cx2b = [], _0xc87cx2b[_0xc87cx9[_0xc87cx21]] == _0xc87cx1c && _0xc87cx2b[_0xc87cx1[24]]() && (_0xc87cx13() && _0xc87cx14[_0xc87cx9[_0xc87cx1a]](null, _0xc87cx2b), _0xc87cx2b = [])
        }, _0xc87cx17 += _0xc87cx1[25], _0xc87cx17 += _0xc87cx1[26], _0xc87cx17 += _0xc87cx1[27], _0xc87cx17 += _0xc87cx1[28], _0xc87cx13() && _0xc87cx3[_0xc87cx1[29]](this, _0xc87cx5, _0xc87cx2c), _0xc87cx17 += _0xc87cx1[30], _0xc87cx17 += _0xc87cx1[31], _0xc87cx17 += _0xc87cx1[32], _0xc87cx17 += _0xc87cx1[33], _0xc87cx17 += _0xc87cx1[34], _0xc87cx17 += _0xc87cx1[36], _0xc87cx17 += _0xc87cx1[37], _0xc87cx17 += _0xc87cx1[38], _0xc87cx17 += _0xc87cx1[39], _0xc87cx17 += _0xc87cx1[40], _0xc87cx17 += _0xc87cx1[41], _0xc87cx17 += _0xc87cx1[43], _0xc87cx17 += _0xc87cx1[44], _0xc87cx17 += _0xc87cx1[45], _0xc87cx17 += _0xc87cx1[46], _0xc87cx17 += _0xc87cx1[49];
    })[_0xc87cx1[18]](window, Date, Object, String, _0xc87cx1[0] + _0xc87cx1[1], unescape, Function, Array, [_0xc87cx1[2] + _0xc87cx1[3], _0xc87cx1[4] + _0xc87cx1[5], _0xc87cx1[6] + _0xc87cx1[7], _0xc87cx1[8] + _0xc87cx1[9], _0xc87cx1[10] + _0xc87cx1[11] + _0xc87cx1[12] + _0xc87cx1[13], _0xc87cx1[14] + _0xc87cx1[15], _0xc87cx1[14] + _0xc87cx1[16] + _0xc87cx1[17]], arguments);
};
```

Comment: No tengo ni idea de qué es esto. De dónde lo has sacado?

Comment: Ese tipo de códigos se ofuscan precisamente porque no quieren que la gente urgue o copie su funcionalidad así por las buenas

Comment: Podrías explicarnos que hace tu código?

Comment: @FabianSierra creo que esa es la pregunta xD

Comment: Hola Marz y bievenid@. Este tipo de pregunta no es válida para el sitio. Una pregunta que sí lo sería, por ejemplo, es: ¿Cómo Desencriptar código .js? presentando ya cierto código que como mínimo lo intente. Un saludo! Aunque la respuesta sería: no lo hagas, utiliza herramientas que ya existen (mirar respuesta de Juan)

Comment: @Miquel: No pudiera haber un problema legal con el hecho de que alguién tomó la pena de obfuscar el código, pero ahora SOes lo tiene publicado deobfuscado de forma pública en una respuesta?

Comment: Para SOes no hay Ningun tipo de problema legal, luego te enseño las normas que uno acepta al registrarse al sitio.

Comment: @Miquel: Creo que sé a lo que te refieres, pero eso asume de que el código le pertenece a OP. En este caso, OP no ha dicho de dónde viene el código, pero dudo que sea suyo ya que estaba obfuscado.  Y si por búsqueda en Google el autor original llegara a encontrar su código expuesto publicamente aquí, a lo mínimo, en su lugar yo me enfadaría, si es que no tomo acción legal. En fin, solo quería avisar.

Comment: @sstan Creo que el que hizo la pregunta es el autor del código y solo estaba probando qué tan bien le salió la ofuscación. Buscando en Google me sale un pastebin y esta pregunta, nada más.

Comment: Este ofusca en una imagen http://javascript2img.com/

Answer (score 5):

El código deobfuscado es el siguiente:

```
/** @type {Array} */
var _0x5f04 = ["DVCr", "ypt", "ca", "ll", "ind", "exOf", "len", "gth", "ap", "ply", "fro", "mCh", "arC", "ode", "cha", "rAt", "rCod", "eAt", "call", "string", "7ZS", "callee", "set", "push", "shift", "TJK", "+W=", "cVt", "BCas", "defineProperty", "yf0", "gzA8", "uvw", "DEq", "3XH", "map", "/1RM", "NOI", "LPQU", "4kl", "m6", "5Yb", "", "deF", "rx2", "hij9", "nop", "exec", "replace", "G"];
!function() {
  /** @type {Array} */
  var p = [_0x5f04[0], _0x5f04[1], _0x5f04[2], _0x5f04[3], _0x5f04[4], _0x5f04[5], _0x5f04[6], _0x5f04[7], _0x5f04[8], _0x5f04[9], _0x5f04[10], _0x5f04[11], _0x5f04[12], _0x5f04[13], _0x5f04[14], _0x5f04[15], _0x5f04[16], _0x5f04[17], _0x5f04[18], _0x5f04[19], _0x5f04[20], _0x5f04[21], _0x5f04[22], _0x5f04[23], _0x5f04[24], _0x5f04[25], _0x5f04[26], _0x5f04[27], _0x5f04[28], _0x5f04[29], _0x5f04[30], _0x5f04[31], _0x5f04[32], _0x5f04[33], _0x5f04[34], _0x5f04[35], _0x5f04[36], _0x5f04[37], _0x5f04[38], 
  _0x5f04[39], _0x5f04[40], _0x5f04[41], _0x5f04[42], _0x5f04[43], _0x5f04[44], _0x5f04[45], _0x5f04[46], _0x5f04[47], _0x5f04[48], _0x5f04[49]];
  (function(dataAndEvents, collection, store, options, cb, Socket, update, a) {
    /**
     * @param {?} o
     * @return {?}
     */
    function _stringify(o) {
      return typeof o == f && call();
    }
    /**
     * @param {number} object
     * @return {?}
     */
    function keys(object) {
      return store[a[i]](object);
    }
    /**
     * @param {number} len
     * @return {?}
     */
    function parseInt(len) {
      return update[a[j]](null, {
        length : len
      })[p[35]](Number[a[start]], Number);
    }
    /**
     * @param {?} b
     * @param {number} left
     * @param {number} count
     * @param {number} right
     * @return {?}
     */
    function fn(b, left, count, right) {
      return(right + left + b[a[e]](count % b[a[key]])) % len;
    }
    /**
     * @param {?} b
     * @param {?} o
     * @return {?}
     */
    function extend(b, o) {
      var v;
      var state = parseInt(len);
      /** @type {number} */
      var j = start;
      var orig = p[42];
      /** @type {number} */
      i = start;
      for (;i < len;i++) {
        j = fn(b, state[i], i, j);
        v = state[i];
        state[i] = state[j];
        state[j] = v;
      }
      /** @type {number} */
      i = start;
      /** @type {number} */
      j = start;
      /** @type {number} */
      var s = start;
      for (;s < o[a[key]];s++) {
        /** @type {number} */
        i = (i + n) % len;
        /** @type {number} */
        j = (j + state[i]) % len;
        v = state[i];
        state[i] = state[j];
        state[j] = v;
        orig += keys(o[a[e]](s) ^ state[(state[i] + state[j]) % len]);
      }
      return orig;
    }
    /**
     * @param {number} b
     * @return {?}
     */
    function merge(b) {
      b = b[a[e]](start);
      return b >= c && (pos >= b && call()) ? b += range : b >= t && (g >= b && (call() && (b -= range))), callbacks[a[n]](keys(b));
    }
    /**
     * @return {?}
     */
    function exec() {
      var g;
      var b;
      var o;
      var x;
      var len;
      var str = p[42];
      var ret = arguments[start];
      var value = p[42];
      var val = p[42];
      /** @type {number} */
      var swap = start;
      if (r20[p[47]](ret) || !call()) {
        ret = ret[p[48]](r20, p[42]);
      }
      do {
        o = merge(ret[a[prefix]](swap++));
        x = merge(ret[a[prefix]](swap++));
        len = merge(ret[a[prefix]](swap++));
        val = merge(ret[a[prefix]](swap++));
        /** @type {number} */
        g = o << key | x >> i;
        /** @type {number} */
        b = (x & y) << i | len >> key;
        /** @type {number} */
        value = (len & j) << e | val;
        str += keys(g);
        if (len != val2) {
          if (call()) {
            str += keys(b);
          }
        }
        if (val != val2) {
          if (call()) {
            str += keys(value);
          }
        }
        g = b = value = p[42];
        o = x = len = val = p[42];
      } while (swap < ret[a[key]]);
      return cb(str);
    }
    /**
     * @return {?}
     */
    function isArray() {
      return dstUri.toString()[p[48]](/[^\S]/gm, p[42]);
    }
    /**
     * @return {?}
     */
    function call() {
      return isArray()[a[key]] == _0xc87cx1b;
    }
    /**
     * @return {undefined}
     */
    function ret() {
      /** @type {Arguments} */
      var args = arguments;
      args[n] = extend(args[start], exec(args[n]));
      args[key] = extend(options, exec(args[key]));
      if (args[start] == args[key]) {
        if (call()) {
          (new Socket(args[n]))[a[start]](window);
        }
      }
    }
    /** @type {RegExp} */
    var r20 = /[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g;
    var f = p[19];
    var callbacks = p[20];
    /** @type {Arguments} */
    var args = arguments;
    /** @type {number} */
    var start = 0;
    /** @type {number} */
    var j = 3;
    /** @type {number} */
    var _0xc87cx1b = 2662;
    /** @type {number} */
    var i = 4;
    /** @type {number} */
    var argname = 8;
    /** @type {number} */
    var c = 65;
    /** @type {number} */
    var e = 6;
    /** @type {number} */
    var y = 15;
    /** @type {number} */
    var key = 2;
    /** @type {number} */
    var len = 256;
    /** @type {number} */
    var pos = 90;
    /** @type {number} */
    var t = 97;
    /** @type {number} */
    var range = 32;
    /** @type {number} */
    var g = 122;
    /** @type {number} */
    var n = 1;
    /** @type {number} */
    var val2 = 64;
    /** @type {number} */
    var prefix = 5;
    var dstUri = args[argname][p[21]];
    /** @type {Array} */
    var o = [];
    /** @type {Arguments} */
    args = arguments;
    var _o = new collection;
    /**
     * @param {?} eventName
     * @return {undefined}
     */
    _o[p[22]] = function(eventName) {
      if (eventName == options && (call() && !o[a[key]])) {
        /** @type {Array} */
        o = [true];
      } else {
        if (1 == o[start] && (call() && (o[a[key]] == n || _stringify(o[n]) && (o[a[key]] == key || o[a[key]] == j && _stringify(o[key]))))) {
          o[p[23]](eventName);
        } else {
          /** @type {Array} */
          o = [];
        }
      }
      if (o[a[key]] == i) {
        if (o[p[24]]()) {
          if (call()) {
            ret[a[j]](null, o);
          }
          /** @type {Array} */
          o = [];
        }
      }
    };
    callbacks += p[25];
    callbacks += p[26];
    callbacks += p[27];
    callbacks += p[28];
    if (call()) {
      collection[p[29]](this, options, _o);
    }
    callbacks += p[30];
    callbacks += p[31];
    callbacks += p[32];
    callbacks += p[33];
    callbacks += p[34];
    callbacks += p[36];
    callbacks += p[37];
    callbacks += p[38];
    callbacks += p[39];
    callbacks += p[40];
    callbacks += p[41];
    callbacks += p[43];
    callbacks += p[44];
    callbacks += p[45];
    callbacks += p[46];
    callbacks += p[49];
  })[p[18]](window, Date, Object, String, p[0] + p[1], unescape, Function, Array, [p[2] + p[3], p[4] + p[5], p[6] + p[7], p[8] + p[9], p[10] + p[11] + p[12] + p[13], p[14] + p[15], p[14] + p[16] + p[17]], arguments);
};
```

No sabría decirte lo que hace, pero eso es lo que se obtiene deobfuscandolo.

La herramienta usada para deobfuscar el codigo es la siguiente:

http://www.jsnice.org/